# I can not Dockerize MySQL and Django App using docker-compose

Tags: python, django, docker

I am trying to Dockerize mysql and Django app but facing a lot of issues can you help me with it.

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'trying',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '159753',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /my_app_dir
WORKDIR /my_app_dir
ADD requirements.txt /my_app_dir/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /my_app_dir/
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - '3305:3306'
    environment:
       MYSQL_DATABASE: 'trying'
       MYSQL_USER: 'root'
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: '159753'
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '159753'
  web:
    build: .
    command: "python trying/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/my_app_dir
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

I was running

```
docker-compose run web trying\manage.py migrate
```

but getting a lot of errors

**error is**
I was running the command and getting this error I want my container to connect with my MySQL server and work perfectly but I am facing issues please help

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\trying\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\trying\manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 341, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 225, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 219, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 153, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'trying.settings'
```

this is the directory structure

[image]

have a look at my project repo. I want to Dockerize this so can you guide me [project](https://github.com/subban358/songs_listing)

Comment: can you share the errors?

Comment: I guess you want to use trying\trying\settings.py but it is considering \trying\settings.py try changing path

Comment: @DARK_C0D3R Hi please have a look at my project repo https://github.com/subban358/songs_listing

I want to Dockerize this so can you guide me

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

First update the dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /my_app_dir
WORKDIR /my_app_dir
ADD requirements.txt /my_app_dir/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Then update the compose file like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
       MYSQL_DATABASE: 'trying'
       MYSQL_USER: 'root'
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: '159753'
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '159753'
    networks:
      - djangonetwork
  web:
    build: .
    command:       
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - |
        python manage.py migrate
        python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./trying:/my_app_dir
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - djangonetwork

networks:
  djangonetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

Finally, in update the `DATABASE_SETTINGS`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'trying',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '159753',
        'HOST': 'db',  # <-- Here
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Comment: you code was showing at first `Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.` So I changed the MySQL port to 3305 but then when I run docker-compose up `manage.py migrate: error: unrecognized arguments: manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` I am getting this error

Comment: Please see the updated answer. Also, probably you don't need to use ports here unless you want to access mysql from your local machine

Comment: it is now saying

`File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in __init__
web_1  |     super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
web_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (-2)")`

Comment: it is showing `ERROR: The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.networks: 'djangonetwork'`

Hey I don't think it will be this much complex can you please go through my repo as and just help me dockerizing it forget about my approach I am new to docker I might be wrong

Comment: My bad. I fixed the issue with yml file.

Comment: still not working can you please just clone the repo and try on your machine if possible

Comment: same thing `super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
web_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (-2)")`

Comment: I am assuming it has something to do with how you have setup your docker.